# Qt app and icu files

Tags: dll, size

I've been searching for hours for a solution to my problem , which is " the size of the dll files " after finishing my project , for example the icu files are too big for my simple app.

I found two solution:

1- recompile qt without icu support " tried to find a good tutorial but i'm out of luck " need a tutorial that thinks about the reader a new user "

2- creating or compiling your own icu , I tried this :

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Compiling-ICU-with-MSVC

but I could not understand it I got stuck here " C:\icu\source> dos2unix * "

I tried this :
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/38489/

but it couldn't work because I have a newer version + another compiler.

can you guys direct me to solve this problem ? if someone have a reduced size of icu that works on qt 5.2.1 with vs 2012 please upload it so I can use it :)