# Qt and executable dll's

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I've posted a few posts about this , and still there's no answer!

I'm assuming lots of people program in Qt creator , I have , it's great.. the only problem is the dll's the the executable file needs to work, most of the size are from icu files!

Let's say your created a program , a simple one that does something , the size is usually around 30mb! with all the dll's!! that's just a lot!

I don't see a lot of posts with the same problem , why is that ? did people figure a solution or something ?

Qt 5.2.1 , msvc 2012

Comment: Because people, who cares about distributive size can compile Qt by themself, without ICU. + compress runtime with UPX.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt app and icu files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611206/qt-app-and-icu-files)

Comment: "I've posted a few posts about this , and still there's no answer!" Please don't do that. This is not a discussion forum. There ideally should be one copy of each question, ever, on SO. Duplicates are subject to closing.

Comment: @Dmitry Sazonov  I guess so , thank you and I'm actually following what Kuba Ober said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [compile Qt to link statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862989/how-to-build-qt-4-8-5-2-statically-under-vs2012-using-the-static-msvc-runtime). An UPX-compressed executable using core + gui + widgets module, with no other dependencies (no need for MSVC runtime!), is about 5MB. The same for Qt 4 is 4MB, so not that big of a difference. You can recompile Qt with ICU disabled if you don't need webkit, as only webkit has a hard dependency on ICU.

Comment: first sorry about the duplicate , I've been looking for an answer for 3 days now , I checked the post , great one ^^ , I think I'll compile a static version then. thank u